# How to mapping an array to another array in efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For these 4 array, 
a1 a2 a3

```
a1 = [5,3,0,2,4,2,...,...]
a2 = [5,3,0,2,4,2,...,...] => store index number, correspond value is in b
a3 = [5,3,0,2,4,2,...,...]

b = [250,300,1,2,70,23,...,...]
```

I want to find an efficient way to generate an array like:

```
 c1 = [23,2,250,1,70,1,...,...]
 c2 = [23,2,250,1,70,1,...,...]
 c3 = [23,2,250,1,70,1,...,...]
```

But using 3 Forloop solving this problem is too slow in my case.
I want to find an efficient way to solve.
For example, mapping 3 array at the same time.

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe your problem further. Will `a1`, `a2` and `a3` always be equal? Can you show your code with the 3 for loops?

Comment: If you have no idea, you can create an empty new `list`, iterate over the `a` list and add each `b` element at `a` index. Also, you can check if the `a` values are lower than the length of `b` list (prevent index of range error).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use the lists `a1`, `a2`, `a3` as index for the list `b`. You can do this efficiently in Python by using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). In your example this would look like

```
c1 = [b[i] for i in a1]
```

If you have a large number of `a` lists the most efficient procedure would be to write them into the rows of one combined array that you could loop through as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can this work for you?

```
c1,c2,c3 = [list(map(lambda x:b[x],array)) for array in [a1,a2,a3]]
```

Comment: This is most likely going to be slower than the three loops OP already mentioned having problems with.